# does angular cache dependencies via constructor injection?

Tags: angular

I have a very strange situation.

I have a service class called `Test1` which has an instance variable `public account = new Subject();` Then this class is injected `into 2 different components`, but those component are `parent-child`. Now what happens is first's component's code changes something into that instance variable(`Test1's account`). It turns out as soon as this change happens, another component is subscribing to it and when changed happened, subscribe happened which leads me to the following question.

Question 1)WHen service class got injected into 2 components, let's say it got injected into compA first, and then I think in compB, it got injected from cache and both components have same class.

QUestion 2) does angular cache dependencies when injecting into constructor?

Question 3) whose job is to to cache dependencies ? is it Provider's object we use in modules?

Answer (score 1):

1. Both components will have same `Instance` depending on which level a service is provided. You can provide services in both modules and components. If it is provided in a module in which both the components reside and no where else, then both will have same instance. If it is just provided in parent component, then again both will have same instance. If it is provided in both the componnets then there will be different instances.
2. No, It does it when we provide. (Using the term `cache` doesn't seem right to me but yeah..)
3. Yes, when we provide, thats when angular will create singletons.